# How to apply .xaml file in windows form

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I need to apply theme file in windows form but I can't. When I use the code below I get error because there is no System.Windows.Application

```
StreamResourceInfo sri = System.Windows.Application.GetResourceStream(
                new Uri("App.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
            var resources = (System.Windows.ResourceDictionary)Load(sri.Stream); 
            var app = new System.Windows.Application();
            app.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(resources);
```

Thank you

Comment: Why don't you just use WPF ?.

Comment: I need to use USBHid component and it works in windows forms

Answer (score 1):

`XAML` is not supported in Windows Worms. `System.Windows.Application` represents a `WPF Application`, and since your are running a `Windows Forms Application` - the `Application` is null.